# Symfony Download streamed

Tags: symfony, nginx, symfony4, nginx-config

I'm trying to **stream a large download file** (up to 4GB) with the Symfony Object : [StreamedResponse](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/StreamedResponse.php)

I'm able to download one file with the code below.

My issue is during this download my server is frost until the end of it.

So What I did wrong !

The issue from my PHP code or my NGINX conf?

Thank you for your help

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test/dl", name="test-download-start")
     * @param string $webDirectory
     * @return StreamedResponse
     */
    public function testDl(string $webDirectory)
    {
        $path = $webDirectory . '\\public\\Softwares\\InitMedia\\5d9b516a8140b.zip';
        $response = new StreamedResponse();
        $response->setCallback(function () use ($path) {
            $handle = fopen($path, 'rb');
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $buffer = fread($handle, 1024);
                echo $buffer;
                flush();
            }
            fclose($handle);
        });
        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/zip');
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="test.zip"');
        return $response;
    }
```

***NB*** :
I tried with BinaryFileResponse it's same

```
    /**
     * @Route("/test/dl2", name="test-download-start2")
     * @param string $webDirectory
     * @return BinaryFileResponse
     */
    public function testDl2(string $webDirectory)
    {
        $path = $webDirectory . '\\public\\Softwares\\InitMedia\\5d9b516a8140b.zip';
        $response = new BinaryFileResponse($path);
        $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename="test.zip"');
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: It would probably be better to hand off the actual download to Nginx, and the X-Accel functionality (aka X-Sendfile). After checking permission, your code sends a header and the server delivers the file from a protected/internal location.